Nestjs unable to resolve my controller dependecies while unittesting
Please i am trying to write a unittest for a bookmark app that i am working on, but anytime i run the test i get a certain error which goes like this
" Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BookmarkController (?). Please make sure that the argument BookmarkService at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
Potential solutions:
- Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
- If BookmarkService is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
- If BookmarkService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing BookmarkService */ ]
  })

"
i have tried browsing the internet for any solution that i can find and i have even included the bookmark service in the provider  but still the problem remains. below is what my test file looks like
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing"
import { BookmarkController } from "../bookmark.controller"
import { BookmarkService } from "../bookmark.service"
import { Bookmark } from "@prisma/client";
import { bookmarkStub } from "./stubs/bookmark.stub";
import { BookmarkServiceMock } from "../__mocks__/bookmark.service.mock";
import { BookmarkModule } from "../bookmark.module";






describe("BookmarkController", () => {
    let bookmarkController: BookmarkController;
    let bookmarkService: BookmarkService;

beforeEach(async ()=> {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        controllers: [BookmarkController],
        providers:  [
            {
              provide: BookmarkService,
              useValue: BookmarkServiceMock,
            },
          ],
    }).compile();

    bookmarkController = moduleRef.get<BookmarkController>(BookmarkController);
    bookmarkService = moduleRef.get<BookmarkService>(BookmarkService);
    
})

describe('getBookmark', () => {
    describe('when getBookmark is called', () => {
        let bookmark : Bookmark []
        beforeEach(async () => {
          bookmark  =  await bookmarkController.getBookmark(bookmarkStub().userId)
        })

        test('then it should call the bookmarkService', async () => {
            expect(bookmarkService.getBookmark).toBeCalledWith(bookmarkStub().userId)
        })
    })   
})
}) 

anyone with a solution should please help..thanks!
i have tried changing the mock and re-injecting the bookmark service in anywayn i can, but i still keep getting the erroryour text

Could you provide the code for your bookmarkController ? Or at least, show its constructor (as it appears to be where the problem occurs)
